# ArcGIS API GraphicsLayer is not visible on map

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers, visibility, graphics, typescript

I'm creating an onClick eventhandler to create a point on every click on the map, but the Graphics layer is not visible;
Has anyone else encountered this? Is there something special I'm supposed to do to show it?

Here is some of the code:

```
        var point = {
            type: "point",
            longitude: event.mapPoint.longitude,
            latitude: event.mapPoint.latitude,
            spatialReference: event.spatialReference,
        };
       
       var simpleMarkerSymbol = {
         type: "simple-marker",
         size: "50px",
         color: [226, 119, 40], // orange
         outline: {
           color: [255, 255, 255], // white
           width: 1
         }
       };
       
       var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
         geometry: point,
         symbol: simpleMarkerSymbol
       });
       
     let pointLayer = this.map.findLayerById("pointLayer") as GraphicsLayer;
     pointLayer.removeAll();
     pointLayer.visible=true;
     pointLayer.add(pointGraphic);
     this.logger.info("nb of graphics : ", pointLayer.graphics.length)
    
     });
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

That all looks correct  - you should double check you have valid values for the latitude and longitude and spatial reference (you should use `wkid: 4326`).

Also, try adding `style: "square"` to the simpleMarkerSymbol.